# array type int[n][n] is not assignable, because of expression must have a constant value

Tags: c++

I got the error: expression must have a constant value on line 4(int cost[n][n]), and further errors base on it, which is "array type int[n][n] is not assignable" .
How do I fix them?

```
 int optimalSearchTree(int keys[], int freq[],  int n)
    {
        /* Create an auxiliary 2D matrix to store results of subproblems */

        int cost[n][n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            cost[i][i] = freq[i];

        for (int L = 2; L <= n; L++)
        {
            // i is row number in cost[][]
            for (int i = 0; i <= n - L + 1; i++)
            {
                // Get column number j from row number i and chain length L
                int j = i + L - 1;
                cost[i][j] = INT_MAX;

                // Try making all keys in interval keys[i..j] as root
                for (int r = i; r <= j; r++)
                {
                    // c = cost when keys[r] becomes root of this subtree
                    int c = ((r > i) ? cost[i][r - 1] : 0) +
                        ((r < j) ? cost[r + 1][j] : 0) +
                        sum(freq, i, j);
                    if (c < cost[i][j])
                        cost[i][j] = c;
                }
            }
        }
        return cost[0][n - 1];
    }
```

Comment: By using the proper containers, e.g.: `std::vector`

Comment: `int cost[n][n];` is not valid C++.

Comment: like std::vector int cost[n][n]?

Comment: @NeilButterworth for a level 1 person its not obvious what the syntax for a n*n vector of vectors is (I will have to look it up) Lets be a bit nice

Answer (score -1):

The standard way to create a dynamically n*n sized 2d array in c++ is like this

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > cost(n,std::vector<int>(n));
```

see [Vector of vectors, reserve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991765/vector-of-vectors-reserve)

Comment: Though quite often it is not a good idea to represent matrix by vector of vectors, but that is a different story.

Comment: @Slava - please post an alternative then. I agree the vec of vec is probably not as fast are pure 2d array

Comment: @pm100 A 1-D array or vector of elements of  size n * n, together with operators or functions to correctly calculate the 1-D index from two 2-D indexes.

Comment: thats such a useful construct its surprising that there is nothing standard for it , maybe in boost?

Comment: can somebody post another answer Slava? Neil B?

Comment: i am only trying to help the OP. I googled for that and found matrix math libraries. If you know a good solution for the question why not post it.