# Convert int[n][n] to vector<vector<int>>

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

We can easily convert an array to a vector with the following:

```cpp
int a[n];

vector<int> b = vector(a, a + n);
```

---

I want to work with matrix, what if I want to convert :

```cpp
int a[n][n];
```

to

```
vector<vector<int>> b = ... // from a
```

with b.size() = n and b[0...n-1].size() = n ?

---

Alternatively I am okay with a solution converting

```cpp
std::vector< std::array<int, n> > a;
a.reserve(n);

vector<vector<int>> b = ... // from a
```

Comment: If your matrixes have constant lengths, i.e. are always rectangular, you probably do not need the flexibility of vectors. Not in at least one of the dimensions.

Comment: Regarding `a.reserve(n)` you should read [Choice between vector::resize() and vector::reserve()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397768/choice-between-vectorresize-and-vectorreserve). `reserve(n)` doesn't do anything meanginful unless you also  insert elements.

Comment: @Yunnosch I agree that is a valid point but I do need it, as I do not have control over the type (need to return a vector<vector<int>>). I coined a solution for https://leetcode.com/problems/spiral-matrix-ii/ using int [n][n].  Hence my question. NB, related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991765/vector-of-vectors-reserve

Comment: Why not use vectors (or `std::array`) from the start? Why do you need to "convert" to a vector?

Comment: I don't think you can do better than using a for loop here.

Comment: `std::vector` has no feature for "adopting" an existing array. You need to copy the array. `std::vector` has a constructor that accepts a pair of iterators, which should make copying pretty easy at least.

Comment: Have you considered using a linear algebra lib, such as [xtensor](https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/)?

Comment: @TaiguaraTupinambás I would like to keep it simple, with only std

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that vector of vector is the best choice of the container for your use case, but if it's out of your control something like this should work:

```
int a[n][n];
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v;
v.reserve(n);
for (int *arr : a) {
    v.emplace_back(arr, arr + n);
}
```

Comment: If you find this solution give you performance problems, note that `vector`s of `vector`s can be surprisingly slow. Each `vector` is a contiguous block of memory, but here you have `n+1` `vector`s and will have to do a bunch of expensive hopping around in RAM to read all of the data you want rather than reading in one big block. It is often better to make one big `vector` of size `n*n` and wrap it in a class that performs the a little bit of math to map the 2D coordinates to a simple 1D index. [Here's a simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301).

Comment: It's a bit harder to use, so don't use it unless you need the speed.

Comment: @user4581301 the question asked for vector of vectors specifically (and OP clarified in the comments that the choice of the type is out of their control). I've just provided a reasonable solution to that problem.

Comment: @DanM. Thank you and +1, I will give it one day before selecting as answer to see if someone can come up with a solution without any loop (unlikely but we never know) ;) I ended up declaring a vector directly `vector<vector<int>> a(n,vector<int>(n));` https://github.com/agavrel/leetcode/blob/master/bit_manipulation/0059_Spiral_Matrix_II/solution.cpp

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL you can likely replace the loop with a `std::for_each` but that's just moving it inside a library function. `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` is no more special than `vector<T>`, so it doesn't have any extra methods/constructors for multidimensional stuff.

Comment: Yes I do agree, there is no need to involve a library function if it is not doing a better job, your solution currently looks like the best approach.